# An uncaught Exception was encountered after loading database libraries on codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter 3 in linux environment, using php 7.2.
Gere is my autoload config in codeigniter:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

and my database config:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'scevas',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

but after I load/save and view my page I'm getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5MjY.png)
I already enable phpenmode mysqli and restart the Apche service but still getting the error, I'm out of ideas and already googled this error but none of those worked for me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**I ALREADY RESOLVED THIS PROBLEM:**
 I forgot to install other packages/modules

```
apt-get install php-pear php7.2-dev php7.2-zip php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql  php7.2-xml
```

then restart apache2 service and it works. 
*NOTE: I ddnt use root user in database,I just add/created another user with granted privileges*

Answer (score 0):

First check if the appropriate extension is enabled in your `php.ini`

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Then, verify via `phpinfo()` if mysqli is well running.

You should also change your db config from this

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] => 'mysqli'
```

to this

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] => 'mysql'
```